# how to make a JButton not clickable in java?

Tags: java, jbutton

I'm looking for a substitute of `.setEnabled(false)`, so that the button is not clickable.

I have read that I could remove the ActionListener from the button, but I just want the specific buttons to be not clickable, and do not know how to do it anyway.

Or how can I get rid of the "selected" effect after clicking a button?

Comment: `I'm looking for a substitute of .setEnabled(false),` - why? How will the user know that the button is not clickable if it is painted normally. I would get extremely frustrated using your application because I would think the button is broken. Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Because in my application I have a grid of JButtons that are used as icons

Comment: You could do some kind of `if (active) { … }` inside your `ActionListener` if you really want to do this.

Comment: `so there is no "selected" effect after clicking it` - again what kind of requirement is this??? How does the user know if anything happened when the icon was clicked. Also, don't forget about users that use the keyboard. How will the user know which Icon has been tabbed to if there is no visual indication???

Comment: @camickr The icons are used to create a road on the map, which should not be selected or tabbed into

Comment: `which should not be selected or tabbed into` - so how do you use the keyboard to select the Icon??? You should never design a GUI for mouse use only!!!

Comment: The idea is not to select the icons, but to change the image of the icon so e.g. by pressing an arrowy key on the keyboard I would change the image  s of 2 icons and simulate the movement in this way. This is why I wanted to get rid of the "selected" effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Because in my application I have a grid of JButtons that are used as icons

Then don't use buttons, use a JLabel which also supports an Icon.

Or maybe use a JList which can also support a grid.

Or if you use a JButton then you need code like:

```
JButton button = new JButton(...);
button.setBorderPainted( false );
button.setFocusPainted( false );
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the problem is how the button looks grayed out, because `setEnabled` really is the way you disable a button - which just means making it not clickable (or did you want it to respond to keyboard input?). If that's the case, then you can change the way it looks by using html:

```
button.setText("<html><font color=black>3</font></html>");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, graying out the button is not the issue here. I want to make it not clickable, so there is no "selected" effect after clicking it